# custom theme for Stepper in chakra ui not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, chakra-ui

I want to show different background color for completed Step. but it is not working.
following i created custom theme for Stepper but it is not working

````
const CustomStepStatus = {
  variants: {
    active: {
      bg: 'primary.50', // Use the custom color for active steps
    },
    complete: {
      bg: 'tertiary.300', // Use the custom color for complete steps
    },
  },
};

const sizes = {
  lg: {
    // select the title part
    title: {
      // change the font size to lg
      fontSize: 'lg',
    },
  },
}

const stepperTheme = {
  sizes,
  StepStatus: CustomStepStatus
}
export const theme = extendTheme({
    components: {
        Stepper: stepperTheme
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

base on [docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/stepper/theming):

> The Stepper component is a multipart component. The styling needs to
> be applied to each part specifically.

so on each size or variant you must specify the component you want to change:

```
  const CustomStepStatus = {
    variants: {
      active: {
        step: {
          bg: 'primary.50', // Use the custom color for active steps
        },
      },
      complete: {
        step: {
          bg: 'tertiary.300', // Use the custom color for complete steps
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

and also fix this:

```
  const stepperTheme = {
    sizes,
    ...CustomStepStatus,
  }
```